# Borderlands Pre-Sequel PC Weapon Swap Glitch?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

A few friends and I were playing BLands Per-Sequel, 4 Claptraps, and one of our players lost the ability to swap weapons; to be more accurate, a single weapon seemed to fill all his weapon slots. We've found nothing on Google or Steam about this error, y'all are his last hope. The error seems to be constant across all his characters.
Anyone got any ideas short of re-installation?

Comment: Can he drop the weapon? Are there other weapons in his backpack?

Comment: He can drop the weapons, and has others in his backpack that can be switched out. It's just  he can only use one.

Comment: So he has one certain gun that all his characters are forced to use? Or does each character have their own specific gun?

Comment: He can use any gun, but he can't swap between weapon slots.

Comment: Hmm. So the real problem is that his weapon-switch button is not doing anything. Is it possible that the key got unbound? What platform is he playing on?

Comment: He's playing on PC. The weird thing is, it goes through the weapon-swap animation. It just swaps to the same gun. He puts the gun away and takes out the same one.

Comment: Is the behavior the same whether he is hosting the game or someone else is?

Comment: Yes, it's the same no matter who hosts.

Comment: And it is the same whether he is using the scroll wheel or numbers 1-2-3-4?